# Unsupported format character

Tags: python, urllib

```
import urllib
url = urllib.urlopen("http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?\
s=%s&a=6&b=19&c=2016&d=9&e=18&f=2016&g=d&ignore=.csv").read() % ("GOOGL")
print url
```

The code above works perfectly fine if I have GOOGL typed in the URL. Why do I get this error when I try to format it in as a string?

```
ValueError: unsupported format character '/' (0x2f) at index 319
```

Answer (score 1):

`% ("GOOGL")` is in the wrong spot.  You must interpolate on the string

```
url = urllib.urlopen("http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?\s=%s&a=6&b=19&c=2016&d=9&e=18&f=2016&g=d&ignore=.csv" % ("GOOGL")).read()
```